# Is it possible to see if there is a parameter whose name matches a given regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I'm speaking of the param name, not the value.
I couldn't really find anything on that.

I'd like to know if there is a paramater whose name matches /[a-zA-Z]+_page/. The value is not relevant.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
params.keys.any? { |key| key.match /[a-zA-Z]+_page/ }
```